# How to use a Model object across a number of Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

SCENARIO: After the user has successfully logged in, I want to create an Account object (Account class is a part of my model) and fetch and store the user's information in it. I want this Account object to be accessible to all my controllers (HomeController, AccountController etc) and also, I want the ability to edit its content from inside any controller. (1) How can I achieve this scenario? (2) How can I pass a model object from one controller to another?

Comment: Do you intend to keep it and later use it in another request? Or just use it during the duration of a (single) request and pass it around?

Comment: I intend to keep it till the user logs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I intend to keep it till the user logs out

Then you can use session. But I suggest not saving a lot of information. So for example you have this model or entity:

```
public class AccountModel {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}
    // and a whole lot more of properties
}
```

I suggest you just store an `identifier` field, either the `Id` or the `Username`. Then when another request comes in and you need to either validate the request or update that same model, you can:

- Fetch the data again for that user and all relevant information
- Update the necessary fields
- Save it in your database

So you would do something like:

```
// to save it in a session after logging in
Session["current_user_id"] = id_variable;
// to retrieve it from session after another request comes in
var id = (int)Session["current_user_id"];
// fetch from your database
// do the necessary update
// persist the changes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would do just as you're suggesting - use session to save the user's AccountID and thereafter use it to fetch his details from the database whenever I wish to.

Comment: You're welcome. Just remember that session expires so be sure to check that the session item is not null.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) How can I achieve this scenario?

You could retrieve the Account model from your datastore when you need to access it.

> (2) How can I pass a model object from one controller to another?

See (1). Since you are retrieving it from the data store you don't need to be passing it around.

Comment: After the user logs in, I want to create an Account object and fetch his details from the database and populate the account object with it. Then, in another controller (whose view provides the user the ability to edit his account information) I want to save the edits to that SAME account object I created earlier and later, save the changes to the database.